# How to cut patterns out of a signal/array?

Tags: java, arrays, pattern-matching, signal-processing

I have following problem:

I have a few signals which are saved in an array. Every signal contains special patterns. I want to cut out these patterns and I want to have them in a new array. (In the picture below u can see two patterns)

Whats the best way of doing this? Is there another possibility than using a lot of loops?

Thx for ur help!

[image: signal example with two patterns]

Comment: How are patterns defined? Noisy sections separated by quiescent sections? Or...?

Comment: yes! thats actually my problem

Comment: How long does it have to be quiet to count as a separation? How quiet does it have to be relative to the average noisiness of the signal? You will need to specify the criteria in more detail to solve the problem.

Comment: I only have these gaps between the patterns. They are differing in length, but let's say the minimum length of a gap is 400 data points

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to record a couple of these pattern sequences and calculate a mean signal from multiple of these patterns and apply a correlation function.

You would put a moving window over your actual signal you want to analyze, and then correlate the values in this window with the mean signal. If the correlation is maximal (or above a certain threshold), you assume that the pattern is just appearing in the signal.